# does multiple classification label need to be converted into one-hot encoding from float value

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have  iris example, the type from sample data has three float values:
0.0, 1.0, 2.0.

The size relationship between them might misleading training model, I just guess.

Am I right? Should it be converted into three vectors using one-hot encoding or other ways?

```
from keras.utils import np_utils

trainY = np_utils.to_categorical(trainY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the iris dataset, there are three possible labels.

When converted to a number you get 0, 1, 2 discrete integers. So, you have three classes for the classification problem.

If you convert them to one hot then use`categorical_crossentropy` else use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: Thanks, @Vitrioil, It works with categorical_crossentropy. I want to know in principle, which of the two methods(integer values and one-hot encoding) is better for multiple classification.

Comment: Choosing either makes no difference, if your labels are already encoded then choose `categorical_crossentropy` otherwise you can choose the other. [There is no loss difference.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/sparse-categorical-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-keras-accuracy?rq=1)